# Visual studio won't import modules for python

Tags: python, visual-studio, import, module

I am using Visual Studio Code Version 1.19.3 and python3 and I have two cases in which python won't import modules from specific libraries.

The first is when importing flask modules such as:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, 
SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
```

It is unable to import any of the above modules

The second case is when trying to use a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

height = [74, 74, 72, 75, 72, 73, 73, 75, 75]
np_height = np.array(height)
np_height_m = np_height * 0.0254
print(np_height_m)

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'
```

I have all libraries properly installed and up to date, and both sets of code work fine when using IDLE instead of Visual Studio. Any input is much appreciated :) Thanks, James.

Comment: Do you have python extension installed?

Comment: Which python extension?

Comment: VS code can support many languages, you need to have extensions installed in order to use a given language. Go to Debug -> Install Additional Debugger and search for Python.